# elsarticle.cls and biblatex incompatibility

Tags: biblatex, elsarticle

I would like to submit a paper to an Elsevier journal, which uses `elsarticle` document class. `elsarticle` loads `natbib` but I've been using `biblatex` instead of BibTeX throughout most of my files (I have a common `.bib` file for all my publications which is `biblatex` compatible right now). The problem is that I have many authors with special characters (like ø, å, ü etc) and BibTeX was giving errors when compiling because of the encoding - this was the reason why I switched to `biblatex` in the first place.

Is there a quick way to make my `.bib` file compatible with BibTeX without manually substituting those special characters with their TeX versions?

Or will Elsevier become `biblatex` compatible soon?

Comment: Do you know the website http://thecostofknowledge.com/ ? Besides, after acceptance your tex file is going to be retypeset by the copy editor using their own internal style. So you don't need to be 100% accurate about the style file and other stuff. There is no need because  it's there for your own convenience.

Comment: Ok. So I could edit elsarticle.cls myself and make it biblatex compatible?

Comment: As you wish but they will ask for a proper `.bib` file with `\"{u}` and whatnot afterwards if the entries are not displayed properly. And yes, they do that. They do other terrible things to your images etc. so you are bound to their archaic workflow not the other way around.

Comment: @percusse and Remus, this might be of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109069/whats-the-correct-syntax-for-accents

Comment: `biber` has an option like `--output_safechars`, which will encode UTF-8 characters into LaTeX-style macros, thus providing you with an ASCII `.bbl` file.  But that is not the same as using BibTeX, which is what I suspect the journal wants/requires.  However, I think I vaguely remember some question on this site about getting from `.bbl` to `.bib` --- but I could be wrong!

Comment: Have a look at [How to upload LaTeX manuscript, tables, figures, and auxiliary files to Elsevier's EES?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86776/15717)

Comment: Does JabRef have an option to 'save as' a bib file with safechars?

Comment: Assuming they haven't changed their upload procedure in the last few years, absolutely do not hack the style file, because you won't be uploading the final pdf, you'll be uploading the raw tex file which will get compiled on *their* server.  You also won't be using BibTeX or BibLaTeX, because you will have to copy and paste the contents of the bbl file into the end of your document, so you'll need to switch the characters to TeX safe anyways.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`biber` will do such a conversion of the text encoding for you in tool mode via

```
biber --tool --output_encoding=ascii --output_safechars file.bib
```

If `file.bib` is

```
@Article{Beauville:Chern,
  author =   {Beauville, A.},
  title =    {Variétés Kähleriennes dont la première classe de
                  Chern est nulle},
  journal =  {J.~Differential Geom.},
  year =     1983,
  volume =   18,
  pages =    {755--782},
}
```

then the converted file looks like

```
@article{Beauville:Chern,
  author = {Beauville, A.},
  title = {Vari\'{e}t\'{e}s K\"{a}hleriennes dont la premi\`{e}re classe de Chern est nulle},
  journal = {J.~Differential Geom.},
  year = {1983},
  volume = {18},
  pages = {755--782},
}
```

Comment: One thing to note - if the input encoding is not ascii (default is utf8) and the output encoding is ascii, safechars is automatically set.

Comment: In French adjectives are written in lower case, even if they derive from proper names. Please write: "Variétés kähleriennes" and not "Variétés Kähleriennes" which is the English style. Ans also I would suggest your protect the first letter of Chern by writing {C}hern so that in some other context your reference is still correctly typeset.

Comment: @yannis The capitalisation is that given in the journal - even in English authors can't agree whether such words should be capitalised or not.  For biblatex use I don't want to write `{C}hern` because of kerning issues.  When converting to `bibtex` I currently check these cases by hand.

Comment: @Swann I know that in English capitalization depends on the journal. But in French it is governed by standard rules, as given in the "Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale" or other similar compendia. Therefore the flexibility which is inherent to bibtex should be deactivated when the reference is in French and many authors do that by enclosing the whole title in double braces. As for {C}hern, I understand the kerning issue (although in cmr10 there is no kern between C and h) but it is more important to retain the capital under all circumstances, don't you think?

Comment: This answer does not work for me with biber version 2.5, since I was not able to disable field names mapping. In other words I get `journaltitle` instead of `journal` in the converted file.

Comment: @StefanoM Hmm...I don't see how to do that with the current version

Answer (score 9):

One can convert a `.bib` file that contains special characters (e.g. umlauts) to a `.bib` file with safe chars (i.e. TeX equivalents for those special characters) using `bibutils`:

```
bib2xml -i unicode mydb.bib | xml2bib > mydb_bibtex.bib
```

`mydb_bibtex.bib` will not throw any encoding errors when compiled with `bibtex`.

Answer (score 8):

From my recent success of a journal submission to Elsevier, I feel it's easier if you put everything (except the figures) into one single tex file and upload as "manuscript".

To integrate the bibliography into `.tex` file is actually easy, you just compile your original `.tex` with the `.bib` file as you normally do. You will find a `.bbl` file is generated (along with other compiled files, `.pdf`, `.aux`, `.log`, etc.). Then you comment out the `\bibliography{...}` line in your `.tex` file and copy all the contents in the `.bbl` file right after the line.

Comment: You could just upload the .bbl file and leave the .tex file intact. It worked for me.